# Почему от подчёркивания ссылки, от элемента ::before остаётся 1px? Как убрать этот глюк?

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1)При подчёркивание ссылки у элемента ::before width = 100%;
2)Когда я отвожу курсор от ссылки у элемента ::before width = 0; , НО не зависимо от 0% остаётся 1px от before.
3)Объясните, почему так происходит, и как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Браузерам не нравится, когда им приходится вычислять позиции и размеры
> элементов на веб-странице. Большинство элементов каким-то образом
> влияют на отображение других элементов. Изменение размеров одного
> элемента может иметь множество непредвиденных последствий.
>
> Изменение width и / или height элемента потребует, чтобы браузер
> вычислил, какие другие элементы (дочерние элементы, смежные элементы
> или родительский элемент) будут затронуты этим изменением и как эти
> элементы должны быть обновлены. Этот процесс называется
> перекомпоновкой и сопровождается перерисовкой.
>
> Это затратные операции, нужно максимально избегать их запуска.
>
> Для анимаций лучше использовать `transform` или `opacity`

Автор: Rik Schennink
Источник: https://pqina.nl/blog/animating-width-and-height-without-the-squish-effect/

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<a>ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Это пока локальный сайт, Автор Я